# How to add an adblock plug-in to the WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, winforms, adblock

I'm making a winform application containing a WebBrowser control. I'm trying to connect to a Web page that contains ads, but it's affecting the loading speed of the page. The adblock plugin for Chrome blocks ads. So is there any way to add that plugin or any other way to achieve the same result?

Comment: The WebBrowser control uses the IE rendering engine. So you *might* be able to use an ad blocking plug-in designed for IE, but I wouldn't count on it. Better options include: (1) using a different control, for example one based around the Chrome or Mozilla rendering engines, (2) just saying no to a WinForms application that re-invents or otherwise wraps a web browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The adblock plugin is just some js script with some browsers specific metadata on top. You can check the source code here: https://adblockplus.org/source 
You can probably sort something out with this (like run the plugin's code after page load)

Comment: Yah but wich Js file should we include